# Django - Grouping by one column (using count)

Tags: python, django

I would like to get such an effect

```
SELECT "restApi_comment"."id", "restApi_comment"."text", "restApi_comment"."movie_id", COUNT("restApi_comment"."id") AS "count" FROM "restApi_comment" GROUP BY  "restApi_comment"."movie_id" ORDER BY "count" DESC
```

but django is based on this

```
obj = Comment.objects.annotate(count=Count('movie_id')).order_by('-count')
```

give me

```
SELECT "restApi_comment"."id", "restApi_comment"."text", "restApi_comment"."movie_id", COUNT("restApi_comment"."id") AS "count" FROM "restApi_comment" GROUP BY "restApi_comment"."id", "restApi_comment"."text", "restApi_comment"."movie_id" ORDER BY "count" DESC
```

**the problem is grouping which is based not on one column (movie_id) but on three (id, text, movie_id).**

[models.py]

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

---

I tried this method

```
obj=Comment.objects.values('movie_id').annotate(count=Count('movie_id')).order_by('-count').values('movie_id', 'text')
```

which gave me such an effect and did not return all the columns

```
SELECT "restApi_comment"."movie_id", COUNT("restApi_comment"."movie_id") AS "count" FROM "restApi_comment" GROUP BY "restApi_comment"."movie_id" ORDER BY "count" DESC
```

Comment: But your first query does not make much sense (normally a database will error on this), since you include a `SELECT table.id, COUNT(table.field) FROM table GROUP BY table.field`, you can not include that in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this `models.py` for testing based on what you're asking for.

```
from django.db import models


class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(
        Movie, 
        related_name='comments',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    text = models.TextField()
```

While the comment count appears to be what you're most concerned with, getting a list of `Movie` objects annotated with (and ordered by) their comment count means starting from the `Movie` model, like this (pulled from the [Django aggregation doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet)):

```
Movie.objects.annotate(count=Count('comments')).order_by('-count')
```

Partial output from a test case to show population and results:

```
>>> from django.db.models import Count
>>> from movies.models import Movie, Comment
>>> 
>>> for title, comment_count in (
...     ('The Meg', 32), 
...     ('Citizen Kane', 126), 
...     ('Meet the Feebles', 1),
...     ('Dellamorte Dellamore', 900),
... ):
...     m = Movie(title=title)
...     m.save()
...     for i in range(comment_count):
...         Comment(movie=m, text=i).save()
... 
>>> for m in Movie.objects.annotate(count=Count('comments')).order_by('-count'):
...     print(m, m.count)
... 
Dellamorte Dellamore 900
Citizen Kane 126
The Meg 32
Meet the Feebles 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
results = []
movies = Movie.objects.distinct()
for movie in movies:
    results.append('name': movie.name, 'total_comments':Comment.objects.filter(movie=movie).count())
```

`results` is a list of dictionaries containing two values, one is key `name` and is used to to differentiate your results. The second value is key `total_comments` and this is a count of how many comments there are for the movie that was queried with `.filter()`

so you could then in a template do:

```
{% for movie in movies %}
    # some layout html with your data in it
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps :)